# About ios tap gesture

Tags: ios

I add a tap gesture on label.
And add an action to change it text.
but when I tap that label, it doesn't have any changes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30sJL.png)

Comment: Please be specific to what you are asking, and it is always best habit to show us your code and describe what you are trying to accomplish and what's not working out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default label UserInteraction become disable. Enable label user interaction like this:

```
label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: Thx~~~~~~~~~~`~

Answer (score 1):

If your action method is not called then please make sure you enable the userInteraction of the Label.

```
self.lblReportDateTime.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

It may help you.... :)

Answer (score 1):

UILabels are not default set to accept touches from user, they are generally used to display certain text.

If you want UITapGesture On UILabel then you must set **userInteractionEnable** property to true on UILabel

You can set property like below

**Swift 3.0**

```
yourLable.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

**Swift 2.3**

```
yourLable.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

**Objective - C version**

```
[yourLable setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DetailViewController.tapFunction))
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tap working")
    }
}
```